# Modulus of continuity of a continuous function

Tags: analysis, uniform-continuity

Let $f : I\subset\mathbb{R} → \mathbb{C}$ be a continuous function on the closed interval $I$. 
A modulus of continuity of $f$ is any real-extended valued function $\omega: [0, ∞] → [0, ∞]$, vanishing at $0$ and continuous at $0$, that is
$\lim_{t\to0}\omega(t)=\omega(0)=0.$

We say $f$ admits $\omega$ as modulus of continuity if and only if,
$$\forall x,x'\in I: \|f(x)-f(x')\|\leq\omega(|x-x'|).$$
Here is my question: Does any function $f$ as above admit a modulus of continuity?

Comment: If you allow $w$ to take the value $+\infty$ then the function $w = +\infty$ everywhere should work no?

Comment: I don't think so because we want $\omega$ to be continuous at $0$ and to be $0$ at $0$.

Comment: @user37238, but there is a condition at $0$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't pay attention to the continuity of $w$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can define it as
$$\omega (t) := \sup_{0 < |x - x'|<t} \frac{\|f(x)-f(x')\|}{|x-x'|}$$
for $t>0$ and $\omega(0)=0$. Since a continuous function in the closed interval is uniformly continuous, $\omega$ will be continuous at $0$.

Comment: Thanks. But why holds $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\omega(t)=0$?

Comment: I explained it in my last sentence. Recall the definition of uniform continuity.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Thanks a lot for your quick answer and time!

Comment: Do you really want to divide by x-x'?